# How to infer function parameter from a union type?

Tags: typescript

I have a union type of functions:

```
function Function1(arg0: string, arg1: any[], name: "hello" | "bye") {
  return name;
}

function Function2(arg0: string, arg1: any[], name: "foo" | "bar") {
  return name;
}


type Functions = typeof Function1 | typeof Function2;
```

Now I want to create a type that takes a tuple where the first position is the actual Function and the second the corresponding "name" argument.

```
const baz = [Function1, "foo"];
```

I tried this:

```
type FooBar<T = Functions> = [T, Parameters<T>[2]];
```

At first it gives me an error at `Parameters<T>[2]` "Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'
"

It almost works but I get all arguments from both functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to *distribute* your `[T, Parameters<T>[0]]` operation over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`, so we can write a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to do so.  Let's introduce the utility type:

```
type FuncThirdArgTuple<T> = 
  T extends (a1: any, a2: any, a3: infer A) => any ? [T, A] : never
```

which dispenses with `Parameters<T>[2]` and just uses [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) directly to grab the third parameter type.

Then if we apply it to `Functions` we get:

```
type FuncThirdArgTupleForFunctions = FuncThirdArgTuple<Functions>
/* type FuncThirdArgTupleForFunctions = 
    [
      (arg0: string, arg1: any[], name: "hello" | "bye") => "hello" | "bye", 
      "hello" | "bye"
    ] | [
      (arg0: string, arg1: any[], name: "foo" | "bar") => "foo" | "bar", 
      "foo" | "bar"
    ]
*/
```

which looks like the type you want.  Let's test it out:

```
let baz: FuncThirdArgTupleForFunctions;
baz = [function1, "hello"]; // okay
baz = [function1, "foo"]; // error
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSsEEYAUBDATgcwAYAuRAZylxjHwBpE991TswBPAbQF16xsBbAKakARAAtBAG0lwRiAD6IRAIzaCRASkQBvAFCJEuQVBC4kfIQG5dAX126U0eEkdowAJhwES5StToMBMwM7Ny8AsJKwHCyCkrKeJo6+obGpuYR1nb2UGwADoKIAGLgTghkiAC8iLkFcMDIpW7ocbWC9Y2ozu7WbcWlACpiMLgAJgCCBAMgeZKCADwDAHxViAOIggAeUIJgoxU4waxs9NjuLOynAMyk1MCCuIjjWpUrx4gA-IgcA-TjXIhSGBBAA3B45fKFEqQIYjCZTGZzIpwXDQspgCrVNGwsaTfDTWYLNFuMhLXQAegAVDVIf0YcNcQjCcjUU1nJjECkDBwvERSBQqDRTkELpweIgLJFxFIZHJFCo1ElXkoJNJYvLVOp6NK1XL4oqAYoud9eT4Bf5hUxRWEJRFRNF1fFEi8ViIHXqVIlte64p7cCIuLpKeTdHMoIgEgAvUjYhnw-GIwQs4ns6xR1YcVzOdDa1WyriWRDk8mIOAAa2wbF06eqmbZGG9MQDheLG1wuBRuiAA)

Comment: Hi, thanks so far. I made a mistake. I need the third argument. I provided only one in the example, sorry for that. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlykOm)?  I'm worried that after this is solved you'll have another edit.  Are we done now or should I hold off until you are?

Comment: Works perfectly fine but intellisense is suggesting all arguments. Is there anyhing we can do?

Comment: Is that a followup question?  Sounds like you should consider posting a new question (after looking for existing ones).  I think IntelliSense isn't going to work how you want with tuples and even if you did it with an object type I doubt you'll get the behavior you want unless the union is a discriminated union.  Anyway I'm not inclined to dig into that since it's out of scope here.